# Is there a function that is monotonic increasing but not cyclically monotonic increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

Could someone provide an example of a function that is monotonic increasing but not cyclically monotonic increasing?

This question comes from reading the statement on page 2 just before Prop 3 [here](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Ekcborder/Notes/CyclicalMonotonicity.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an $N\times N$ matrix $A$ and the function $f(x)=Ax$. For $f$ to be cyclically monotone, you need $f$ to be the gradient of a convex function, and so $A$ must be symmetric and positive semi-definite. For $f$ to be monotone, it is enough that $A+A^T$ be positive semi-definite.